# The specified value "NaN" cannot be parsed, or is out of range in the console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building an exchange project, I need to use jQuery/JavaScript to get data from a select option and pass the value to an API URL.

I don't get the right value when I run my code I keep getting The specified value `"NaN"` that cannot be parsed, or is out of range in the console, what am I doing wrong here. can someone help me check this code?

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // some variables

  var baseCurrency = 'BTC';

  var baseNumber = 1;

  var targetCurrency = 'USD';

  var targetNumber ;

  var url ;

  currencyConverter(baseCurrency, baseNumber,targetCurrency,targetNumber)

  // get base currency value

  $("#base").change(function () {
    // base currency

    baseCurrency = $(this).children("option:selected").val();

    // call currencyConverter function

    currencyConverter(baseCurrency,baseNumber,targetCurrency,targetNumber)


  });

  // get base currency number

  $("#baseNumber").change(function(){

    // base number

    baseNumber = $(this).val()

    // call currencyConverter function

    currencyConverter(baseCurrency,baseNumber,targetCurrency,targetNumber)

  })

  // get target currency value

  $("#target").change(function () {
    // target currency

    targetCurrency = $(this).children("option:selected").val();

    // call currencyConverter function

    currencyConverter(baseCurrency,baseNumber,targetCurrency,targetNumber)

  });

  // get target currency number

  $("#targetNumber").change(function(){

    // target number

    targetNumber = $(this).val()

    // call currencyConverter function

    currencyConverter2(baseCurrency,baseNumber,targetCurrency,targetNumber)

  })


  // function to convert BaseCurrency to TargetCurrency

  function currencyConverter(baseCurrency, baseNumber,targetCurrency,targetNumber)
  {
      // api url

      url = "https://coinlib.io/api/v1/coin?key=659b81f02b22b218&pref="+targetCurrency+"&symbol="+baseCurrency

      // make a get request to api

    

      $.get(url,function(data){
          console.log(data.price)

          for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data.price)) {
            
            var result = value * baseNumber;

           $("#targetNumber").val(result);

          }
          console.log(`data.price.${targetCurrency}`)
      })
  }

  function currencyConverter2(baseCurrency, baseNumber,targetCurrency,targetNumber)
  {
      // api url

      url = "https://coinlib.io/api/v1/coin?key=659b81f02b22b218&pref="+baseCurrency+"&symbol="+targetCurrency

      // make a get request to api

      $.get(url,function(data){
          console.log(data.price)

          for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data.price)) {

            console.log(value)
            
            var result = value * targetNumber

           $("#baseNumber").val(result)

          }
          console.log(`data.price.${targetCurrency}`)
      })
  }


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Currency Converter in Javascript</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <br><br>
            <h1 style="text-align: center;">Currency Converter</h1>
            <form id="myForm">
                <br><br>
                <label for="Base Currency">Base Currency</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="base">
                    <option>USD</option>
                    <option>BTC</option>
                    <option>ETH</option>
                    <option>LTC</option>
                    <option>BCH</option>
                    <option>ZCASH</option>
                    
                </select>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="baseNumber" value="1">
                </div>
                <label for="Target Currency">Target Currency</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="target">
                    <option>BTC</option>
                    <option>USD</option>
                    <option>ETH</option>
                    <option>LTC</option>
                    <option>BCH</option>
                    <option>ZCASH</option>
                    
                </select>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="targetNumber">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
</html>
```

Comment: except "NaN" cannot be parsed, any other msg or line number shown?

Comment: @tsecheukfung01 the values shows up in the console but gives me wrong value in the input value

Comment: what is data.price

Comment: @chiliNUT the data.price is 1 BTC = 49325.5920 USD

Comment: can someone help me get the solution to this issue

Comment: Could you be more specific on what your issue is? Where exactly in your code do you expect something else  to happen?

Comment: @r3dapple it is giving me a wrong data value in the inputs but if i check in the console i see the the correct value and also i see this warning message in the console The specified value “NaN” cannot be parsed, or is out of range. i need the correct conversion to appear in the id inputs. it is showing me wrong conversion values

Comment: when i run my code it gives me wrong readings of the current price but when i check in the console i see the right current price, can someone please help me check the code i tell me what am doing wrong. i will really appreciate any answers. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Removed the for loops in your two currencyConverter methods. You were essentially iterating over your data.price value so when it got to the decimal point in the value '.' it failed since '.' is not a number (NaN).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // some variables

  var baseCurrency = 'BTC';

  var baseNumber = 1;

  var targetCurrency = 'USD';

  var targetNumber ;

  var url ;

  currencyConverter(baseCurrency, baseNumber,targetCurrency,targetNumber)

  // get base currency value

  $("#base").change(function () {
    // base currency

    baseCurrency = $(this).children("option:selected").val();

    // call currencyConverter function

    currencyConverter(baseCurrency,baseNumber,targetCurrency,targetNumber)


  });

  // get base currency number

  $("#baseNumber").change(function(){

    // base number

    baseNumber = $(this).val()

    // call currencyConverter function

    currencyConverter(baseCurrency,baseNumber,targetCurrency,targetNumber)

  })

  // get target currency value

  $("#target").change(function () {
    // target currency

    targetCurrency = $(this).children("option:selected").val();

    // call currencyConverter function

    currencyConverter(baseCurrency,baseNumber,targetCurrency,targetNumber)

  });

  // get target currency number

  $("#targetNumber").change(function(){

    // target number

    targetNumber = $(this).val()

    // call currencyConverter function

    currencyConverter2(baseCurrency,baseNumber,targetCurrency,targetNumber)

  })


  // function to convert BaseCurrency to TargetCurrency

  function currencyConverter(baseCurrency, baseNumber,targetCurrency,targetNumber)
  {
      // api url

      url = "https://coinlib.io/api/v1/coin?key=659b81f02b22b218&pref="+targetCurrency+"&symbol="+baseCurrency

      // make a get request to api

      $.get(url,function(data){
          
            var result = data.price * baseNumber;

           $("#targetNumber").val(result);
      })
  }

  function currencyConverter2(baseCurrency, baseNumber,targetCurrency,targetNumber)
  {
      // api url

      url = "https://coinlib.io/api/v1/coin?key=659b81f02b22b218&pref="+baseCurrency+"&symbol="+targetCurrency

      // make a get request to api

      $.get(url,function(data){
         
            var result = data.price * targetNumber

           $("#baseNumber").val(result)
      })
  }


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Currency Converter in Javascript</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <br><br>
            <h1 style="text-align: center;">Currency Converter</h1>
            <form id="myForm">
                <br><br>
                <label for="Base Currency">Base Currency</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="base">
                    <option>USD</option>
                    <option>BTC</option>
                    <option>ETH</option>
                    <option>LTC</option>
                    <option>BCH</option>
                    <option>ZCASH</option>
                    
                </select>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="baseNumber" value="1">
                </div>
                <label for="Target Currency">Target Currency</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="target">
                    <option>BTC</option>
                    <option>USD</option>
                    <option>ETH</option>
                    <option>LTC</option>
                    <option>BCH</option>
                    <option>ZCASH</option>
                    
                </select>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="targetNumber">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
</html>
```